# how to count the number of online users

Tags: python, pylons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who's Online in Pylons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767875/whos-online-in-pylons)

We have a project on the pylons. And now the task is to count all users are on the site. Do this with a session does not work, because the lifetime of the session for about a day. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project (but in django), I'm store user id in database with time of last request and show all users for last 5 minute.

Comment: thats good, but how i can intercept requests in pylons?